# Login works only for last user in the database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

For some reason the login only works for the last user in the database. I have a `while` loop, but I think it makes the program to go to the last user. I tried using `if` statement but then only the first user can log in.

```
  if (username!=null && password!=null) {
    pagename = "main";
    } else {
    username = request.getParameter("username");
    password = request.getParameter("password");

            while(results.next()) 
            { 
            if(results.getString(2).equals(password) && results.getString(1).equals(username)) 
            { 
            pagename="main";
            } 
            else 
            { 
            pagename="start";
            } 
    }
  }
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: This is one of the cases where we need to be careful with using loops

Comment: -1; this could have been solved by just using a debugger...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are copying the entire DB table into Java's memory and doing the comparison in a `while` loop over all records. You are not aborting the `while` loop when there's a match with a record, so it continues looping over the remaining records and so the `pagename` get overridden with "start" everytime.

You need to add a `break` statement:

```
if (results.getString(2).equals(password) && results.getString(1).equals(username)) { 
    pagename="main";
    break;
}
```

Or, better, let SQL do the job it is designed for, selecting and returning **exactly** the data you need:

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username=? AND password=MD5(?)");
preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

if (resultSet.next()) {
    pagename = "main";
}
else {
    pagename = "start";
}
```

That's more efficient and sensible.

Comment: Thank you for the mysql explanation

Answer (score 0):

Why would you loop through the whole table to do this? What if you have 1000000 records? You should query the database with WHERE clause passing the username and password parameters and then simply check if there are returned row or not.