# Creating sessions for my login page and counting number of unsuccessful login

Tags: java, session, servlets, authentication, logout

This works fine. Now I wanna create a session after user logged in and also redirect to  security questions once the number of unsuccessful attempts to login is 3. How can I do that?

How to create a user login and logout session? And how to count the number of login attempts?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mutualfund", "root", "");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        String uname = request.getParameter("username");
        String pass = request.getParameter("password");
        String query = "SELECT * FROM `login_table` WHERE `username`=\""+uname +"\" and `password`=\""+pass+"\"";

        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(query);            

        if(result.next())
        {
            System.out.println("entered into if loop");
            if (result.getString(1).equals(uname)
                    && result.getString(2).equals(pass)) {
                System.out.println("Uname and pass are correct");
                if (result.getBoolean(7) == true) {
                    System.out.println("redirecting to admin profile");
                    response.sendRedirect("displayFunds.jsp");
                }
                else if ((result.getBoolean(7) == false)
                        && (result.getInt(3)==0)) {
                    System.out.println("first time login for customer, redirecting to change pass");

                    response.sendRedirect("changePassword.jsp?name="
                            + uname + "&&pass=" + pass);

                }
                else if ((result.getBoolean(7) == false)
                        && (result.getInt(3)==1)) {
                    System.out.println("active customer login");
                    response.sendRedirect("custProfile.jsp");
                }
            }

            else {

                response.sendRedirect("loginFailed.jsp");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Admin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to put the number of login attempts in a session attribute.

Comment: as i said i donno much or u can say almost nothing abt sessions!

Comment: As an additional useful reading: [Session Tracking](http://www.java-programming.info/tutorial/pdf/csajsp2/08-Session-Tracking.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need a session variable to store in login attempts. So the first line of your doGet() must be something like this:

```
// Do not create session if it doesn't exist
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
int loginAttempts=0;
try{
  loginAttempts = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("LOGIN_ATTEMPTS").toString());
  loginAttempts++; //if code comes here then the user has already made a login attempt and therefore icrease the counter
}catch(Exception ex){
  //if error then that means that the user has never made a login attempt because the attribute was not found
  session.setAttribute("LOGIN_ATTEMPTS",1);
}
```

Then after you validate the user credentials you should see if the login attempts counter is equals to a number and forward the request appropriately to the view you want.

Comment: then wont it increment the count same for different login credentials? if user1 tried first and second time user 2 tried then the count would be 2 ?

Comment: @APPUcool No, it won't be 2. `loginAttempts` is declared as a **local variable**. For every method invocation, where the above peace of code was declared, the `loginAttempts` will be created again and initialized to 0. Again, it is **not static variable** (in Java local variable can't be static anyway), so it won't preserve its previous value. Local variables are created when the method, constructor or block is entered and the variable will be destroyed once it exits the method, constructor or block. Read here: [Java Variable Types](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm)

Comment: Yes but if i give the above code in doget it is not recognizing session as an attribute in dopost and if i try writing this piece of code in dopost the LOGIN_ATTEMPT id always equal to 1... since the servlet is called everytime i try to login(again) the LOGIN_ATTEMPTS is being set 1 everytime and a new session is created everytime :(

Comment: you can always get the session grom the request Object as shown above